# Links should not look the same as plain text

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks, accessibility

This image shows three users in the comments on [German Meta](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/289):

[image]

One of them is deleted and therefore lacks a link to their profile. However, all of the links look like regular text so it's impossible to know what text is a link. In fact, a new user may not realize that there are any profile links.

Another example from Writing Meta, where the line is completely covered by the linked text going past the descender:

[image: linked "3" and "5"]

The same thing happens on [Spanish Meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/250). Ditto for [French Meta](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/450). [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/114185) on both sides (meta and main). Possibly other sites too.

Can this be change so that there's an [underline and a color difference](https://www.hawaii.edu/access/2019/04/17/37-link-identified-only-by-color/) for links?

(Links everywhere in the design should have their own color.)

Comment: Area 51 Discussions has the same problem as well.

Comment: All of the sites you're listing here are recently-redesigned, so it looks like I may need to see if we're missing a link color attribute for those sites.

Comment: The reason is colored tag cards. They should be black

Comment: @SnackExchange While many of the affected sites do have monochrome colored tags, Bitcoin SE (and its meta) don't. In other words, that's a coincidence.

Comment: @Laurel The problem is doubled in bitcoin SE. The links are black in both main and meta sites.

Comment: @Laurel Oh, btw in bitcoin SE the "Ask question" card is black just like per-site metas.

Comment: @Laurel I have found that the color of plain text and those links differ very slightly! #0C0D0F for plain text, and #23272A for links. But it's a very bad contrast and it should improve.