# Please make all blue tags black and gray in per-site metas

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, per-site-meta

In most per-site metas common tags have black (and gray) cards; an example is [Meta Physics SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/).

But there are some sites that have colored common tag cards such as [Meta Philosophy SE](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). And the color of tag cards are exactly the color used in Meta SE.

The deep blue (and light blue) colored tags in those per-site metas have two disadvantages:

1. When the tags are blue the links are like plain text, but when black we have colored (orange/brown) links (see the above examples and also [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382462/links-should-not-look-the-same-as-plain-text) question). Of course, in [Meta Quantitative Finance SE](https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com) the no-contrast is between plain text and *visited* links.
2. With blue tags the per-site meta looks like a main site.

So please make all of the blue tags black in those per-site metas. All per-site metas are *supposed* to be universally lookalike.

Other examples include meta sites for [Bitcoin SE](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com), [Spanish SE](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com), [German SE](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com), [French SE](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com), etc. Note that in Bitcoin SE, both main and meta sites suffer the issue (There are also some other sites with the main site only that has no contrast between plain text and the links).

Comment: I *think* this is a duplicate of [my previous request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382462/323179). (Your question is a little hard to understand.)

Comment: @Laurel I see. I will change my question to address only colored tag cards.

Comment: At least for your two examples, they're both sites that have custom themes. As such, it might make sense to request this on the metas for those specific sites. (If you do want to make this as a request for all sites with custom themes, it would probably be more useful to list all of the specific sites this issue occurs on.)

Comment: @V2Blast I can make other examples, but I don't know all of them. SE mods know all of them for sure.